# Google Maps - Pre-geocoding many addresses?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I have about 1600 addresses that I need to plot on my map.  I don't want to geocode at run time, because I believe it will take too long.  Instead, I would like to geocode the addresses in advance, add their Lat/Long values to a table, and read from the table at run time.  Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how/where to geocode a batch of addresses.  Will one of you explain it to me and/or point me to a good tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the Google Maps Data API. The Geocoding section will be of interest to you ([See API docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)). Just write a PHP script to:

1) Loop through your addresses

2) Send HTTP request (use CURL or just `file_get_contents()`) to `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false`

3) Parse the JSON response

4) Store in your database

Be aware that Google has usage limits. I'm not sure what those are so 1600 requests may or may not be an issue. You may want to add delays between requests and/or run it over several days.

Comment: Just an update, Google has officially ended support for the Maps Data API: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/11/maps-data-api-deprecation-announcement.html

Comment: You might want to look into Fusion Tables, which is the current recommended migration path if you've used the Maps Data API: http://www.google.com/fusiontables/public/tour/index.html

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing.  Instead of the HTTP request, I used myGeoCoder.getFromLocationName.  Then, I added the lat/long to new fields on my table.

Comment: Careful, you're treading close to the edge of the Terms of Service for that API. See section 10.1.3, b and c: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms -- but I think if you only keep the values very temporarily, you'd be OK. (But you still can't do them *en masse*.)

Answer (score 1):

In the interests of steering clear of TOS violations and performance problems/throttling, you might consider looking into an alternative service.

I work for a company called [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) where we geocode and verify addresses. While Google will make a best guess of the validity of an address (and thus the accuracy of the geocoding), something that is [CASS-Certified](http://smartystreets.com/what-is/cass-certification) will first make sure the address exists before returning the lat/lon coordinates. We have a service called [LiveAddress API](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api) which does this.

- You can perform bulk geocoding with our API (up to 100 addresses per request)
- You can store the results (1600 addresses is actually a really small number. We can handle datasets as large as tens of millions on a regular basis).
- It's fast -- and no throttling or usage limits; you pay for what you use.

From what you've mentioned, I think this would meet your needs. Let me know if you have any other questions.